# Wordpress - Show random post with JS, not PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have this page containing recent posts at the bottom. I have set it to randomly show me three posts from the same category as the current post. Heres the loop:

```
<!-- Related Posts =========================================== -->

<div class="relared-posts-heading">
    <h2>SIMILAR INSIGHTS</h2>
</div>



<div class="container blog-card-container">
    <div class="card-columns">
<?php 
   // the query
   $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'orderby' => 'rand', 
     'cat' => '-14',
     'posts_per_page' => 3,
   )); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

      <!-- Conditional a Link =========================================== -->

      <?php 
        if(get_field('quote') == ''){
        $yourTag = "<a href='".get_the_permalink()."'>" ;
        } else {
        $yourTag = "";
        }
      ?>


      <div> <?php echo $yourTag; ?> </div>
              <div class="card">

          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="blog-thumb-container-2">
              <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>
            </div>
          </a>

          <div class="blog-meta-container-2">
            <p class="blog-cat-label"><?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
              <h2 class="blog-card-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
              <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>
              <p><strong><?php the_author(); ?></strong> | <?php echo get_the_date(); ?> </p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </a>



  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
  <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

This works fine currently.

The trouble is, when finished, the site will be behind a clients custom cache and he tells me that PHP randomisers wont work as it will just show the cached version. He suggested I do any randomising using Javascript!

So firstly - is this possible? Secondly, How would I go about targeting this is javascript!? Thanks for looking!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't be able to randomize a post in this way for the caching reason.

What you can do instead is use an Ajax call to dynamically fetch and insert a random post...

```
$.get('/wp-content/themes/SomeTheme/random.php?v=' + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000))
.done(function(resp) {
  $('.random-post').html(resp);
})
.fail(function(xhr) {
  // handle error (xhr object contains the response)
});
```

And then create a separate `random.php` file in your theme and put the code to randomly return a single post in there. Note, that you don't need to put the whole layout around the post (don't include `header.php` etc). That's because this exact HTML fragment will be sent to the frontend and inserted dynamically.

The `?v=` parameter is required for cache busting so that it fetches a new post each time.

Comment: I revised my answer slightly to include `?v=` which is required depending on how you're caching things.

Comment: Thank you for this - just so I have it right, I would create a loop that displays a single blog post in it's own php file - Then add this code to my Wordpress template file inside the loop on the page to pull in 3x the single blog posts?  - Will this now run the risk of the post duplicating if each one is random?

Comment: I tweaked my answer above slightly, I forgot to include the local variable `resp` in the arguments. To answer your other question, that comes down to the way you query the random.php file. What you can do is change the url to be `random.php?v=123&count=3`, so if you want it to give 3 random posts you can say `count=3` if you have another area of your site where you want to change that you could say `count=2`. There is the possibility that BETWEEN widgets you might have duplicates, if you really wanted to fix that you could tweak the functionality slightly by...

Comment: specifying a range in the intiial call, like `&range=1-2&count=3` and in the other one `&range=3-4&count=2`), that way its a random post within the last 1-2 weeks, and in the ohter widget its a random post in the last 3-4 weeks. Thats going quite deep into details... generally the chance of a random post would be quite rare, and if you have only 1 widget area on your page then it doesnt matter anyway

Comment: Another option is to make the php file return json instead, so like: `{posts: [{...}, {...}])`, and make jQuery fetch that file using the `?count=5` parameter. This count would be the TOTAL number of posts you want, across the entire site. From there, you could take those 5 results and instead of inserting them using the `.html(resp)` command you would build out the actual widgets using loops or a templating library like DoT.js.

Comment: As far as what goes in the PHP file, everything i've mentioned can be done with the `WP_Query` function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I've given you a range from simple to more advanced, it really depends on 1) how many widgets there are per page, 2) how much you dont want duplicates even if the chance is fairly low. If you have only 1 widget on your whole site then `?count=X` is enough. If you have multiple then its up to you on whether you want to use the `range` method or to fetch ALL the posts you want for the entire page in JSON format, and then 'build' each html widget area manually, using the posts you fetched (and using each one only once)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the entire funtionality as a shortcode.